# Haskell - How to continue to code "merge Sorted" a three lists

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, merge

I know how to merge two sorted lists in Haskell, however, I have no idea how to merge three sorted lists. I wrote some code, what should I do next?

I am really new for Haskell programming, I watched the "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!" as a start to learn Haskell. I've tried to follow the format of two sorted lists merge:

```
mergeS :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mergeS [] [] [] = []
mergeS (x:xs) [] [] = (x:xs)
mergeS [] (y:ys) [] = (y:ys)
mergeS [] [] (z:zs) = (z:zs)
mergeS (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) -- I do not know how to write from here
```

The correct answer will be somethinig like:

mergeS :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]

mergeTwoLists :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]

...

mergeS x y z = mergeTwoLists x (mergeTwoLists y z)

Comment: please include your code for merging *two* sorted lists, so it can be used as a starting point.

Comment: Why do you need a merge for three sorted lists?

Comment: This is not exhaustive, you miss when exactly one list is empty, e.g. `merge [] (y:ys) (z:zs)`

Comment: @WillNess, I think it's a tad early for that, especially considering this is a new person.

Comment: `mergeThreeLists x y z = mergeTwoLists x (mergeTwoLists y z)`

Comment: @AJFarmar can u give me more details?

Comment: @Cubic cf. https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2007-July/029391.html

Comment: @AJFarmar just gave you the whole code. I'm not sure how to make that more detailed.

Comment: @Mathaskers510520 There are no more details to give—I have shown you the full implementation.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for the website, it helps!

Comment: @dfeuer OK. undv'ed.

Answer (score 2):

You know how to merge two sorted lists. Now just do it twice.

Comment: ... and *only then*, inline, fuse and optimize! :)

Comment: @WillNess, yeah, sure. But that seems like overkill for this exercise.